# Do USB Audio Interface XLR Inputs show up as separate devices on Windows over the USB connection?

Tags: audio, usb, windows, interface

Devices I'm looking at specifically are these 3. I also want to clarify that I mean does it show up as 4 different devices in Windows sound settings? I don't plan on using these devices with a DAW.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07QQ2YTHN/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QQ2YTHN)

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07L9V5JBB/ref=crt_ewc_title_dp_2?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L9V5JBB)

[https://www.amazon.com/BEHRINGER-Audio-Interface-4-Channel-UMC404HD/dp/B00QHURLHM/ref=sr_1_2?crid=3B3B8SOMPE6C5&dchild=1&keywords=behringer+audio+interface&qid=1594071536&s=musical-instruments&sprefix=BEHRINGER+audio+%2Cmi%2C160&sr=1-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00QHURLHM)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the driver.

I used to have a Behringer UMC404HD and that showed up as 2 devices, it had 2 channels combined into each device (channel 1+2 and channel 3+4).

My TASCAM interface for example shows up as a single 16 channel device.

I don't know about your other two products. You could contact the manufacturer.

One side note: Behringer is doing a mediocre job in regard of documentation and the USB driver crashed very often with my interface. However it offers a lot for the price.

Comment: Ah appreciate that response. Now that I know it's driver dependent I guess I should ask a different question on this board. Hoping I can find someone that has experience with a device that shows each input or at the very least, each stereo pair as its own device when connected via USB. With drivers that don't crash constantly like Behringer